# Center the top th in a html table

Tags: javascript, html, center

I have an html table which the content is gathered from an API using Javascript. I'm trying to center the text in the top row of my html table(the table is in a modal window) and it just won't center. It always stays in the left side.

```js
if (data.foods) {
  //here is the top row->  var div = "<tr><th>" + data.foods[0].food.desc.name + "</th></tr>" + "<tr><td>Nutrition Facts</th><td>per 100gr</td></tr>";
  data.foods[0].food.nutrients.map(nutrients => {
        let tableList = "<tr><td>" + nutrients.name + ": " + "</td><td>" + nutrients.value + nutrients.unit + "</td></tr>";
        div += tableList;
        nutrientData.innerHTML = div;
        //modal 
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        modal.style.display = "block";
        span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
```

```css
/* modal content-box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  text-align: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.modal-content table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px red;
  line-height: 1.35;
}

.modal-content tr,
.modal-content td {
  border: solid 0.5px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <table id="nutrientData">
    <!--api nutrient data here-->
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Photo:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the first row you're trying to center either contain only a single `<td>`/`<th>`, or the text in only in the first `<td>`/`<th>`, while the next one remains empty.

In either case, you can do the following:

1. Make sure the first row has only 1 `<td>`/`<td>`
2. Use colspan, like: `<td colspan=2>`

More about `colspan` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Comment: While the first row had only a ```<th>``` , the second solution actually fixed my problem. Why's that? Thank you very much anyway!